# How to update label text through onclick event in ASP.net (Razor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a **button** so as to update a label's text after 'onclick'. I found some solutions achieved by using ASPX but I want to use Razor.

```
//The following is achieved by ASPX

//View
<asp:label id="myLabel" runat="server" />

//Onclick event
myLabel.Text = "my text";
```

How to do this with Razor view engine in ASP.net MVC?

Comment: Wht sql.net in title?

Comment: That was a typo, will fix it

Answer (score 3):

Are you coming from a asp.net webforms background?

You should update the text with javascript. The runat="server" doesn't exist anymore and shouldn't be used according to MVC principles.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a property in your model like:

```
ControllerNameModel
{
   ...
   public string LabelText {get; set;} = "my text"; //my text is the default value
}
```

Then in your Controller you can change the Label Text:

```
public IActionResult ControllerName(ControllerNameModel model)
{
     model.LabelText = "new text for label"
     return View(model); // return the view with modified model
}
```

And in your view you should have your label like this:

```
<label for="something">@Model.LabelText</label>
```

P.S.: Change **ControllerName** to the appropriate name of your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple ViewBag to do this. Set the value in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyCustomTitle = "Title"
    return View();
}
```

... and in the view use it like this:

```
<label>@ViewBag.MyCustomTitle</label>
```

Comment: No, it is on the server side. If you want to use onclick, then you will need javascript. If this is the case, then please update your question.